# sculpt negative thickness doesn't remove stroke completely

Tags: grease-pencil

I am trying to **remove strokes** with **sculpt negative thickness** however a bit of the stroke remains (notice the light gray strokes, those are letfovers that shouldn't be there), can I just remove it completely?

[image]